# AngularJS $http 'Accept' header cannot be set

Tags: angularjs, json, xml, rest, http

I'm trying to make an $http request and I would like the endpoint that I am making the request to to make return a response in the format of 'application/xml'.  However, I cannot seem to set the 'Accept' header to 'application/xml'.  I am using the following code:

```
$http({
            url: restUrl,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/xml'
            }
        }
```

Despite explicitly setting this header, the request still uses the 'Accept': 'application/json' as the header for the request.  If anyone else can replicate this, I would argue that it is a bug in Angular.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  The API is returning JSON and you'd like to transform it into XML?

Comment: I don't want to transform from JSON to XML, I want to be able to set the 'Accept' header to 'application/xml' so that the server responds with xml instead of json. Even when I set the header like in my above code, the request sent to the server STILL contains the header 'Accept' : 'application/json' even though I set it to 'application/xml'

Comment: The code you provided properly passes Accept:application/xml... https://jsfiddle.net/r0m4n/kmy67LL2/

Comment: Hm I see that that works here... I'm wondering now why its not working in my environment... If maybe the server replaces the header?

Comment: The network tab in your browser should give you all the information you need from a client side perspective... After the request is sent, its hard to say what happens on the other end of the wire but I wouldn't expect anything to be modifying it. Where are you validating the accept header?